# Setting DataLoadOptions for DataContext in F#

Tags: linq-to-sql, f#, datacontext

Is it possible to set the [DataLoadOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548760.aspx) on a data context in F#? So far I have had no luck because the DataLoadOptions.LoadWith() takes a [System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.lambdaexpression.aspx) which seems impossible to instantiate in F#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this should be possible. You'll need to reference `FSharp.PowerPack.Linq.dll` which adds support for translating F# quotations (written using `<@ fun x -> x.Foo @>`) to C# expression trees. Something like this should do the trick:

```
#r @"FSharp.PowerPack.Linq.dll"

open System
open System.Linq.Expressions
open Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.QuotationEvaluation

let e = <@ Func<int, int>(fun x -> 1 + x) @>
let lambda = e.ToLinqExpression() :?> LambdaExpression
```

Note that the quotation creates a `Func<...>` delegate, which is translated to expression tree that can be converted to `LambdaExpression` (normal F# functions are represented differently).